# Sequential Criterion for Functional Limits

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

[image]

How can I use the sequential criterion for functional limits to show that the following limit exist and compute the limit:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sqrt{|x|}\cos\left(1/x\right) \ \text{for} \ x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$$

---

My attempt:

I have a hunch the limit is 0, but I can't really use the sequential criterion to show it is 0. What I've done so far is just try one particular sequence, i.e., define $x_n = \frac{1}{2 n \pi}$, clearly $(x_n) \rightarrow 0$.

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}\cos\left(1/x\right)$. Then $f(x_n) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 n \pi}}\cos\left(2n \pi\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 n \pi}}$. So $f(x_n) \rightarrow 0$.

Now the thing is, this is only one particular sequence, to use the sequential criterion, I need to show for ALL sequences.

How do I finish the question?

---

Working off the hint:

Let $(x_n)$ be any sequence in $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ such that $(x_n) \rightarrow 0$. Then $0 \le \sqrt{|x_n|}\cos\left(1/x_n\right) \le \sqrt{|x_n|}$, using the squeeze theorem, we have $f(x) \rightarrow 0$.

Since $(x_n)$ was arbitrary, we are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Choose any sequence $x_n$ in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ converging to zero. Using the fact that $|\cos x| \le 1$ for all $x$,

$$|f(x_n)| \le \sqrt{x_n}$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, please see my edit, is my argument correct?

Comment: @user40333 Yes, it's fine.